# Custom ActionResult and viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I've writen a very simple Actionresult which derives from ViewResult

```
    public class FormResult : ViewResult
    {
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.Controller.ViewBag.Form = "value";

            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
```

It basically just adds a value to ViewBag.

Then I'm returning it in the action method.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return new FormResult();
    }
```

The problem is, the ViewBag is empty in the appropriate view.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass `ViewData` from the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    return new FormResult
    {
        ViewData = ViewData
   };
}
```

If you see the source code of the `View()` method this what it is

```
protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
    }

    return new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = viewName,
        MasterName = masterName,
        ViewData = ViewData,
        TempData = TempData,
        ViewEngineCollection = ViewEngineCollection
    };
}
```

The `ViewData`, `TempData`,.. are passed from the controller.